# 's' or 'z': 'musealisation' versus 'musealization'

Tags: orthography

As I understand, the term in itself is not consensual, but is there a preferred spelling for musealisation/ musealization, or is it just the 'usual' question of the British/American spelling?

Comment: Welcome to the site! It is most probably just the usual s/z issue, which, by the way, is not entirely geographical: many British writers also use z in many (most?) words, like Oxford University Press. What reason do you have to suspect that this word might be different?

Comment: @Cerber, maybe the OP, before asking, had an inspiration about that word, rather than a 'reason'.

Comment: What is [musealisation](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/spellcheck/english/?q=musealisation)?

Comment: @Andrew, yes, you are right, but then it was a quasi-mystical nocturnal inspiration.

Comment: If the word doesn't exist, the answer to this question is 'no'.

Comment: @TimLymington The word *does* exist, though at the moment mostly in scare quotes, and sometimes without. https://www.google.com/#q=musealization+OR+musealisation (eg., Anne Hathaway’s cottage stops being a cottage and becomes a heritage object.)

Comment: @Kris: the results I get are all either transliterations (mostly from German or Italian) or academic jargon, that is a term defined by an author to cover a technical concept that has no word in English. As such, the spelling and pronunciation are up to the coiner; OP recognized that "the term is not consensual". Whether it is 'a word' may be a matter of personal definition.

Comment: @TimLymington The term is, and probably will stay, an 'academic term' for the most part. That may not disqualify it from being accepted into the general lexicon. Just when the scare quotes get discarded is for the authors to decide.

Answer (score 1):

The etymological source seems (at least related to) *musealizzazione* (?[the 1970s](https://www.google.com/search?q=musealizzazione#q=musealizzazione&start=0&tbs=cdr:1,cd_max:1980)) with a **z**, in a **European** language (?Italian).

Early translators may have variously rendered it with an 's' or a 'z' into English.

Considering the origins, ***musealization*** with a 'z' would be a more reasonable, if not the rational choice.

GoogleSearch returns ~15,600 results for the two versions together (**z**: ~11,800; **s**: ~4,530), with ~1,750 in books (~1,210, ~671).

Answer (score 0):

On spelling: Cerberus is entirely correct. (The fact that many North Americans **believe** that -z- is exclusively theirs and that all British-English users write -s- has been canonized in Microsoft's spellcheck software, and is in fact statistically pushing BrE users towards -s- and away from -z-) 
As to the word itself: Its cognates are well established in several Romance languages, but a first search on the world's favourite search engine doesn't turn up any examples written by a native speaker of English in the first few pages, so it seems clear that it's being loaned from the writers' L1 (we might unkindly call this L1 interference). However, English doesn't seem to have a widely recognized term for this concept, i.e. the installation of an **artefact** or other object in a museum (and by implication, the probable termination of its career outside the museum). In other words, the *institutionalization* of an object, comparable to the institutionalization of a human being when installed in a care facility, including the pejorative connotation. So I think it's not unreasonable to run with it in English as well and see if it finds its niche.